# Exception EInvalidPointer because using Unicode chars in array

Tags: arrays, delphi, unicode, delphi-xe

I'm trying to change chars style by using Unicode chars in Delphi XE8, 
everything work well except when close application I get
Error `Exception EInvalidpointer` here the code

```
procedure ChangeStyle(OriginalText, DecoratedText: TsMemo; DecoList: TsListBox);
var
  StyleChars, TempText: string;
  Len, I: Integer;
  TextArray, StyleArray: array of UnicodeString;
begin
  // Put Style chars in array
  StyleChars := DecoList.Items.Strings[DecoList.ItemIndex];
  SetLength(StyleArray, 23);
  for I := 1 to 23 do
    StyleArray[I] := Copy(StyleChars, I, 1);

  // Put originl text in array
  Len := OriginalText.GetTextLen;
  SetLength(TextArray, Len +1);
  for I := 1 to Len do
    TextArray[I] := Copy(OriginalText.Text, I, 1);

  // Set style to chars

  for I := 1 to Len do
  begin
    if (TextArray[I] = 'A') or (TextArray[I] = 'a') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[1]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'B') or (TextArray[I] = 'b') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[2]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'C') or (TextArray[I] = 'c') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[3]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'D') or (TextArray[I] = 'd') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[4]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'E') or (TextArray[I] = 'e') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[5]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'F') or (TextArray[I] = 'f') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[6]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'G') or (TextArray[I] = 'g') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[7]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'H') or (TextArray[I] = 'h') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[8]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'I') or (TextArray[I] = 'i') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[9]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'J') or (TextArray[I] = 'j') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[10]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'K') or (TextArray[I] = 'k') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[11]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'L') or (TextArray[I] = 'l') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[12]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'M') or (TextArray[I] = 'm') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[13]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'N') or (TextArray[I] = 'n') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[14]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'O') or (TextArray[I] = 'o') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[15]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'P') or (TextArray[I] = 'p') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[16]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'Q') or (TextArray[I] = 'q') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[17]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'R') or (TextArray[I] = 'r') then
       TempText := TempText + StyleArray[18]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'S') or (TextArray[I] = 's') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[19]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'W') or (TextArray[I] = 'w') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[20]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'X') or (TextArray[I] = 'x') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[21]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'Y') or (TextArray[I] = 'y') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[22]
    else if (TextArray[I] = 'Z') or (TextArray[I] = 'z') then
      TempText := TempText + StyleArray[23]
    else
      TempText := TempText + TextArray[I];

  end;
  DecoratedText.Text := TempText;
end;
```

I tried `TextArray := nil;` and `StyleArray := nil` but it didn't fix it;
Also tried `TextArray, StyleArray: array of String;`
When I used `TStringList` the Exception gone but it doesn't support Unicode
So I think it's something about `Arrays` or `Unicode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetLength(StyleArray, 23);
for I := 1 to 23 do
  StyleArray[I] := Copy(StyleChars, I, 1);
```

You write beyond the end of the array here. Dynamic arrays use zero-based indexing. So, valid indices are 0 to 22 inclusive. That explains the runtime exception that you encounter.

Given the one-based indexing everywhere else you probably want to allocate one extra element:

```
SetLength(StyleArray, 24);
```

and simply ignore the first element with index 0.

However, I suspect that much of this code can simply be removed, as I explain below.

The huge if statement could be replaced by some arithmetic instead. Note that `ord('A') - ord('A') = 0`, `ord('B') - ord('A') = 1`, and so on.

The two character arrays seem rather pointless to me. You may as well index directly into the strings. I'd re-write the code by removing those two arrays.

I think I would also avoid using concatenation to populate the string. Allocate it at the start since you know its length ahead of time. The assign to each indexed element directly.

I don't know why you think that `TStringList` does not support Unicode. It does.

Comment: thank you `SetLength(StyleArray, 24);` did the job but I didn't understand it I have only 23 chars so why arrays should be 24?  I know my code look stupid i'm new to arrays and strings this is first time I use arrays and `TStringList` I tried it and it didn't display Unicode chars

Comment: David told you why you need to add an extra element to the array. "*Valid indices are 0 to 22 inclusive ... Given the one-based indexing everywhere else, ...*".  A dynamic array uses **0-based indexes**. If you allocate 23 elements, you can only use indexes 0..22. Instead of hard-coding your loop to 1..23, you can use `I := Low(StyleArray) to High(StyleArray)` instead.

Comment: If you want to use **1-based indexes** 1..23 instead, the array needs 24 elements so that index 23 is valid. Since your array is small and fixed-length, you could use a static 1-indexed array instead of a dynamic array: `StyleArray: array[1..23] of UnicodeString;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I understand it now, thank you for your time and detailed explanation I really appreciate. your code look really simple I will try it now

Comment: @user You accepted an answer that did not answer the question that you asked. Why?

Comment: the 2 answers answer my question and correct it so I accepted the last one that was more useful for me, should I change it or what? I'm new to this site and don't the rules about accepting answers

Comment: No. You asked specifically about a runtime error. Remy's answer does not mention the runtime error. Normally, we try to keep the site quite focussed on answering the specific question that was asked. However, I don't mind the accept. Please leave it as it is. Remy has fleshed out in code the ideas that I wrote about in my answer, and did so very well. as always.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that, I didn't mean it; you both helped and did your best but only one answer can be accepted, you right we should focus on the answer that answering the specific question, now I have to Accept your answer because it's answering my specific question and I'm sorry about this situation.

Comment: @DelphiLover Don't worry. And in fact now I'm embarrassed by having stolen the accept from Remy. I'd be quite happy for it to go back to Remy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you don't have to be embarrassed it was all my fault so I just corrected it, you didn't steal anything, you deserved it; I'm sure Remy don't mind one accept. and you too, we just want to accept the answer that answering the specific question and it was yours.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shown can be greatly simplified:

```
procedure ChangeStyle(OriginalText, DecoratedText: TsMemo; DecoList: TsListBox);
var
  StyleChars, TempText: string;
  Len, I, Idx: Integer;
  Ch: Char;
begin
  // Put Style chars in array
  StyleChars := DecoList.Items.Strings[DecoList.ItemIndex];

  // make sure the array is big enough
  Assert(Length(StyleChars) >= 23, 'StyleChars must be at least 23 characters');

  // Get original text
  TempText := OriginalText.Text;
  Len := Length(TempText);

  // Set style to chars    
  for I := 1 to Len do
  begin
    Ch := TempText[I];
    case Ch of
      'A'..'S', 'W'..'Z': begin
        // convert uppercase letters A..Z into indexes 0..25
        Idx := Ord(Ch) - Ord('A');
        // no styles for letters T..V, so decrement the indexes for W..Z
        if Idx >= 22 then Dec(Idx, 3);
        // Now replace the character
        TempText[I] := StyleChars[Idx+1];
      end:
      'a'..'s', 'w'..'z': begin
        // convert lowercase letters a..z into indexes 0..25
        Idx := Ord(Ch) - Ord('a');
        // no styles for letters t..v, so decrement the indexes for w..z
        if Idx >= 22 then Dec(Idx, 3);
        // Now replace the character
        TempText[I] := StyleChars[Idx+1];
      end;
    end;
  end;

  DecoratedText.Text := TempText;
end;
```

Comment: The code work perfectly, but I didn't understand those few lines `Assert(Length(StyleChars) >= 23);` and this line `Idx := Ord(Ch) - Ord('A') + 1;` why you use `Ord('A')` and why `+1` and `if Idx >= 22 then Dec(Idx, 3);` why `22` and `3`, I hope if you have time you explain it to me, thank you for your time

Comment: `Assert()` is checking if `StyleChars` is at least 23 chars, otherwise an exception is raised (if asserts are enabled), as that is how many chars the loop is accessing. `Ord()` retrieves the numeric value of a character, where `A` is 65, `Z` is 90, `a` is 97, `z` is 112 (see the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com)). I'm converting letters into indexes regardless of uppercase/lowercase: `A-A=0`, `a-a=0`, `B-A=1`, `b-a=1`. `+1` is because the index is *0-based* but `StyleChars` is *1-based*. `Dec()` decrements the indexes for `W..Z` and `w..z` as you don't have styles for `T..V` and `t..v`.

Comment: Now I understand the whole code, I really appreciate what you did to me, you saved me much time and work to understand all this, thank you very much